# What is the runtime for Repository's default "findById" function in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, repository

For simple @PutMapping (see below), does it take the order id and look for the specific order throughout the entire orders table? or does it go to get that specific order directly?

orderRepository is inherited from JpaRepository; database is MySQL

```html
//Update a order:
    @PutMapping("/orders/{id}")
    public Order updateOrder(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long orderId, @Valid @RequestBody Order orderDetails) throws OrderNotFoundException {
        Order order = orderRepository.findById(orderId).orElseThrow(() -> new OrderNotFoundException(orderId));
        order.setMerchant(orderDetails.getMerchant());
        order.setStore(orderDetails.getStore());
        Order updatedOrder = orderRepository.save(order);
        return updatedOrder;
    }
```

Comment: [Log the generated query](https://www.baeldung.com/sql-logging-spring-boot) - is the query using the primary key of the table?

Comment: I guess you need to look up how SQL queries are run. In any case, you lookup orders table from the database to get that specific order row

Answer (score 0):

You can see the sql queries that occur by adding the following lines to the properties (application.properties) file:

`spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true`

findById hibernate query formed in line is as follows:

`select order0_.id as id1_0_0_, order0_.name as name2_0_0_ from app_order order0_  where order0_.id=?`

The `id` field is searched as a where condition in the order table. In a `WHERE` clause, you can specify a search condition (logical expression) that has one or more conditions. All rows for which the predicate in the `WHERE` clause is True are affected (or returned)

You can read these articles as a suggestion:
SQL WHERE clause is [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp).

Spring Data JPA core concepts is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.core-concepts).